# Google Appengine LocalSearchService fails in test due to lock contention

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In tests, I find that the Search Service implementation sometimes has problems with lock contention.  I see errors such as the following:

```
Dec 30, 2017 6:09:28 PM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService indexDocumentForApp
SEVERE: Unable to access index
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/[path]/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/indexes/dGVzdA/Ym9va3Rh..P/write.lock
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:85)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1562)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1090)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.getIndexWriter(LocalSearchService.java:800)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.indexDocumentForApp(LocalSearchService.java:290)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.indexDocument(LocalSearchService.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.invokeApiMethodJava(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:559)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:516)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This does not appear to be related to any fundamental race conditions in the test itself, but causes flakiness with tests.  Does anyone have a work around for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is due to using the Search Service Indexer in a test without a search service test config.  Adding the correct config to the offending tests solved the problem.

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(
                new LocalSearchServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
```